# Implementar radio buttons utilizando a biblioteca unform

Tags: array, react, radiobutton

Recebo o seguinte array de uma API:

Array **exam**:

```
[
  {
    id: 2,
    question: 'Questão 1:',
    essay_question: false,
    value: '2.00',
    options: [
      {
        id: 1,
        option: 'Opção A',
        correct: false,
        question_id: 2,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        option: 'Opção B',
        correct: true,
        question_id: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    question: 'Questão 2:',
    essay_question: false,
    value: '2.00',
    options: [
      {
        id: 5,
        option: 'Opção A',
        correct: false,
        question_id: 2,
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        option: 'Opção B',
        correct: true,
        question_id: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Preciso iterar e mostrar o array **options** como radio buttons.
Estou iterando o array exam da seguinte forma:

```
{exam.map(e => (
  <li key={e.id} >
    <p>{e.question}</p>
    <RadioInput name="user" options={[e.options]} />
  </li>
))}
```

Estou utilizando o unform (https://unform.dev/examples/radio) para registrar os inputs.

O componenten RadioInput é este do gist abaixo, copiei da mesma forma como está no site com a documentação:
https://gist.github.com/fredarend/b50103f73ba682510bf951326620250e

Porém tenho várias dúvidas, o id do array options é do tipo number e não string, eu não possuo itens no array options chamados value e nem label, somente id e option. Não estou conseguindo entender qual a forma correta de implementar esse componente.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz alguma alterações aqui no código

o `App` ficou da seguinte forma:

```
export default function App() {
  function handleSubmit(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
  }
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((n) => {
        return (
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} initialData={{ radio: n.id }}>
            <li key={n.id}>
              <p>{n.question}</p>
              <RadioInput name="User" options={n.options} />
            </li>
            <button type="submit">Open</button>
          </Form>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Tem que englobar toda aplicação, por conta dessa biblioteca `@unform/web`

E no seu `RadioInput` fiz as seguites alterações:

Mudei sua interface já que o id é do `type number`, alterei o `label` por `option` e removi o value

**Você pode alterar a sua interface pra se adequar ao seu `array`**

```
interface Props extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  name: string;
  options: {
    id: number;
    option: string; //label
  }[];
}
```

Posteriormente ajustei o `return` do `RadioInput`:

```
return (
  <>
    {options.map((option) => (
      <label htmlFor={String(option.id)} key={option.id}>
        <input
          ref={(ref) => inputRefs.current.push(ref as HTMLInputElement)}
          type="radio"
          name={name}
          defaultChecked={defaultValue.includes(String(option.id))}
          value={option.option}
          {...rest}
        />
        {option.option}
      </label>
    ))}
  </>
);
```

O `htmlFor` quer receber uma `string`, então converti o id para string e fiz az demais alterações em `defaultChecked`(não precisa dele) e mudei o `value` para receber `option`